# How to use classes implemented in exe from dll

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am building a simple game engine and a game in it. The idea is to have most of the functionality and basic class hierarchy implemented in the engine which should be an exe and then to have a dll which will implement specific game given the tools the engine provides. Similar to id engines such as [idTech4](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php).

The engine would then load the dll, acquire an instance of the game, give the game pointers to whatever functions and data structures the game needs and call methods such as `game->update();` on the game instance. So far so good.

I would like to have things like basic classes like Entity, Transform, Vector3 etc. implemented in the engine. Then in the game what I want is to for example derive my character from Entity.

`class Character : public engine::Entity {...};`

Things like this compile all right since I include the headers from the engine but they do not link since I do not use the obj files nor the cpp files form the engine. I know why this does not work. As far as I know my (reasonable) options are:

1. Make these classes header only - this way it will always compile everywhere.

I don't want this since it would increase compile times, binary size etc.

2. Put the common functionality into a lib or a dll.

This would work, but a **lib** file would mean that I have the same classes compiled (linked) both in the exe (engine) and dll (game) - this seems sloppy.
**Dll** would work but it seems like a lot of work with all the exports and imports I would need to do to both the engine and game.
**Also probably most importantly** both lib and dll approach share common issue which is that during development I may end up moving various class a lot from and to them since the class hierarchy may change a lot etc.

My question is, is there another way around this? For me this seems like a pretty useful feature to have a hierarchy of classes in exe usable from a dll. I tried even very silly things such as making the linker use the *.obj* files generated during engine compilation, but it did not work unless I specified all *.obj* files one by one (I am using Visual Studio 2017).

I do not want to give up the modularity of this design.

**Edit**: As dlls are platform specific let's consider Windows (although I guess other platforms would be similar).

Comment: I am a bit confused about the engine being the exe and the game the dll. Wouldnt make more sense the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are wanting to utilize dynamic loading, but I think you might have things flipped around the wrong way. The exe usually has the game code and the **.dll** has the game engine logic and classes. You load the **.dll** in the **.exe** code and register different things with the engine so your game code gets updated and rendered.

I'm thinking now as I type this if there is a way to flip it, but it would require a paradigm shift in your game design logic where the game only provides update and render functions to the game engine or something. That is really all you can rely on as the engine has to be generic enough to handle games.

If I think of anything ground breaking I'll post it here, but in the mean time  here is some info on dynamic loading to help you get started. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading

Comment: In my mind it would make sense to have an engine which controls the main game loop where it just calls game->update(). If the game is the exe everyone who wants to make a game needs to take care of the main loop. Having the engine as dll seems more like having a framework. I should probably dive into the IdTech4 code and see how exactly it is done there. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Yeah it is always good to see how successful projects are doing things to get inspiration. FYI there is a game development stack exchange website where this stuff might be more appropriate. Here is a question about separating engine from game from level editor that you might find interesting. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26520/level-editor-game-duplicating-rendering-game-specific-code/26521#26521

Comment: You are right on the concept of the engine having to be generic enough to call update on game stuff, but you want programmers to be able to use your engine code at least to register objects. To do that you need to have a way for them to "load" that code to use. That is why it usually goes in a .dll. You can't load from an .exe unless you are setting up shared memory.

Comment: At the end of the day we are discussing how your engine code gets compiled and loaded by some other code that has actual game logic. However you achieve that is irrelivant as long as an independent programmer can register game objects with the engine (in a normal setup, engine in .dll) or can register game engine signals with game logic code (my best guess at a design for what you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Put the common functionality into a lib or a dll.
> ```
>
> This would work, but a lib file would mean that I have the same
>   classes compiled (linked) both in the exe and dll

nope, it wouldn't.
The classes would be compiled and available on the shared library (.so on linux, .dll on windows, .dylib on mac), and your executable would call **that** particular method, from the shared library. it would not be compiled again in your executable.

Take a look on **all** frameworks or libraries in C++ are implemented:

- The **public** part is **exposed** on the headers

  - `__dllexport(true)` on the classes / functions.
- The **private** part is **hidden**

  - Private shouldn't even exist on the public headers unless it's a d-ptr
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer
  - This adds more security torwards binary compatibility
- Do not worry about increase of load times if you use shared library approach, it's negligible.

Comment: The part you quote talks about a lib (static) approach. Dynamic approach has other disadvantages I talk about. Thank you anyways, I may switch things around, although the IdTech approach seems really nice.